# Carousel and list in Dialogflow

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have a question about the Carousel and list selector. How to use `actions.intent.OPTION` in Dialogflow for Actions on Google? I have tried adding `actions_intent_OPTION` in event section  of every intent that the user will be selecting. But every time the response came from a single intent.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you include in your question screen shots of several of the intents that you think the user should be selecting and a screen shot of the event that is being triggered?

Comment: @Prisoner I can't add image because my reputation is less than 10. Now what to do?

Comment: So with all the images you sent me added - can you explain them? Which intent is getting triggered when an option is selected? what happens if they speak a response instead of saying it?

Comment: @Prisoner When an option is selected for example if adverbs is selected then adjectives is triggered instead of  adverbs 
If a user just speaks adverbs instead of selecting the list, then the  adverb intent is triggered which is alright.

Comment: What do you think @Prisoner ? What to do?

Answer (score 0):

An API.AI/Dialogflow event tends to override anything that may have been "said" by the user, so Dialogflow's processing stops when it gets the first event that matches and handles that as the Intent. Option processing tends to be done in fulfillment. Rather than trying to match the option key or title against any phrases, anything said that matches the title or key will return the key as the matched "phrase".